# A.R. Text Translator for android

Tags: android, translation

I am building a student project, it is reimplementation of a popular Augmented Reality app called [Word Lens](http://questvisual.com/us/). Just a quick description

"this app picks text from image(camera)camera and translates it to any language." Mine is a simpler case. I only need to translate only from English to Urdu.

I've already extracted the text from image. I need to translate it now. One solution is use the Google translate API which is not free. Is there any other free API like Google's or is there any other solution.

Comment: bing translator similar google's

Comment: @Manmohan if you would write that in Answer, i could accept it....

Comment: i am doing this in that hope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bing translator api which is similar to google's. Here is the start up guide link and u can find more using google or their portal. Link is as follows.

```
http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/translator
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis
```